# Stop working in Android Studio 's Emoulator

Tags: android

I have an easy problem with my little calculator in android studio(below is my code).

When I run this in Emulator App Stop working. Can anybody help me?

```
package com.blah-blah.padideh.tamrin3;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;


public class Activityone extends Activity {

    Button calculate=(Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
    TextView firstnumber=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.editText);
    TextView secondnumber=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.editText2);
    TextView Result=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.result);
    double num1,num2;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_farshid);
        calculate.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                num1=Double.parseDouble(firstnumber.getText().toString());
                num2=Double.parseDouble(secondnumber.getText().toString());
                Result.setText("Sum:\t"+(num1+num2)+"\n"+
                "Multiple:\t"+(num1*num2)+"\n"+
                "Minus:\t"+(num1-num2)+"\n"+
                "Divide:\t"+(num1/num2)+"\n"+"Good Luck");

            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: can you post the log from logcat

Comment: Did the answer solve your issue?

Answer (score 0):

package com.blah-blah.padideh.tamrin3;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;

```
public class Activityone extends Activity {


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.activity_farshid);

// Now you can find your views
Button calculate=(Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
final TextView firstnumber=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.editText);
final TextView secondnumber=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.editText2);
TextView Result=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.result);
final double num1,num2;

calculate.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {

        num1=Double.parseDouble(firstnumber.getText().toString());
        num2=Double.parseDouble(secondnumber.getText().toString());
        Result.setText("Sum:\t"+(num1+num2)+"\n"+
        "Multiple:\t"+(num1*num2)+"\n"+
        "Minus:\t"+(num1-num2)+"\n"+
        "Divide:\t"+(num1/num2)+"\n"+"Good Luck");

    }
});
}
}
```

you cannot attempt to find a view before you call setContentView() in an Activity.

Comment: This is also have error .Android Studio say me you must declare num1 ,num2,result,firstnumber and secondnumber final.!

Comment: @Bashid you should read up more on java and learn to look at logcat. These are simple concepts in java and android.

Comment: Thanks for your comment .You say right.I need to look more carefully in my code and Think about that logical.

Answer (score 0):

Yeah.After a few Logically look.I found my Fault.Good Luck

```
 import android.app.Activity;
 import android.os.Bundle;
 import android.view.View;
 import android.widget.Button;
 import android.widget.TextView;


 public class FarshidActivity extends Activity {




@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {


    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_farshid);

    Button calculate=(Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
    final TextView firstnumber=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.editText);
    final TextView secondnumber=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.editText2);
    final TextView Result=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.result);



    calculate.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            double num1,num2;


            num1=Double.parseDouble(firstnumber.getText().toString());
            num2=Double.parseDouble(secondnumber.getText().toString());
            Result.setText("Sum:\t"+(num1+num2)+"\n"+
            "Multiple:\t"+(num1*num2)+"\n"+
            "Minus:\t"+(num1-num2)+"\n"+
            "Divide:\t"+(num1/num2)+"\n"+"Good Luck");

        }
    });
}
```

}